# How to create Loop object on the LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I wonder how LLVM can create Loop object.

There are a lot of objects related to Loop such as LoopInfo, LoopBase, Loop, etc.

But I can't find the location of LLVM source code where they create those objects.

I want to know how they track the back-edge, and how to identify that is a Loop.

So to speak, I want to learn whole principles about detecting and analyzing Loop information on the LLVM

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways you can go about implementing a conventional loop. One does not use the `phi` instruction and one does, however, both use the `br` operator.

Take a look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      printf("Test.\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Here, I have generated an example using Clang with command `clang -S loop.c -emit-llvm`, causing it to implement the first option:

```
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [7 x i8] c"Test.\0A\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval
  store i32 0, i32* %i, align 4
  br label %for.cond

for.cond:                                         ; preds = %for.inc, %entry
  %0 = load i32* %i, align 4
  %cmp = icmp slt i32 %0, 10
  br i1 %cmp, label %for.body, label %for.end

for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.cond
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([7 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0)) #1
  br label %for.inc

for.inc:                                          ; preds = %for.body
  %1 = load i32* %i, align 4
  %inc = add nsw i32 %1, 1
  store i32 %inc, i32* %i, align 4
  br label %for.cond

for.end:                                          ; preds = %for.cond
  ret i32 0
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #0
```

First, we create identifiers to represent our `i` and return value variables and then set them each to 0. It goes to the first label and begins the loop, starting with calculating a boolean value resulting from the `icmp <cond> <ty> <op1>, <op2>` instruction, where `slt` = "signed less than". If `%i` is less than 10, true will be stored in `%cmp`, else, false will be stored.
The overloaded syntax of the `br` instruction  that follows, `br i1 <cond>, label <iftrue>, label <iffalse>` defines that if `%cmp` is true, the program will jump to the `iftrue` label, in this case, `%for.body`, otherwise, it will jump to the `iffalse` label, in this case, `%for.end`. Summarized, this instruction will enter the loop body if `%i` is still less than 10, and if it reaches 10, it will exit the loop. With this final knowledge of the `br` instruction, the behavior of the rest of the program should be obvious.

Now, while the second method is much shorter, it is slightly more complicated. I generated this code using Clang with command `clang -S loop.c -emit-llvm -O1`, i.e., tagging on the level 1 optimization flag, causing it to implement the second option:

```
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [7 x i8] c"Test.\0A\00", align 1
@str = private unnamed_addr constant [6 x i8] c"Test.\00"

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  br label %for.body

for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.body, %entry
  %i.02 = phi i32 [ 0, %entry ], [ %inc, %for.body ]
  %puts = tail call i32 @puts(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([6 x i8]* @str, i32 0, i32 0))
  %inc = add nuw nsw i32 %i.02, 1
  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %inc, 10
  br i1 %exitcond, label %for.end, label %for.body

for.end:                                          ; preds = %for.body
  ret i32 0
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare i32 @puts(i8* nocapture readonly) #1
```

Ignore the funny syntax of the increment technique `%inc = add nuw nsw i32 %i.02, 1`, it is simply integer math overflow error handling. We are focused on the `phi` instruction Here is the description from the manual:

> At runtime, the ‘phi‘ instruction logically takes on the value
>   specified by the pair corresponding to the predecessor basic block
>   that executed just prior to the current block.

So, let's bring the code in question to our attention again:

```
for.body:
          %i.02 = phi i32 [ 0, %entry ], [ %inc, %for.body ]
          %puts = tail call i32 @puts(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([6 x i8]* @str, i32 0, i32 0))
          %inc = add nuw nsw i32 %i.02, 1
          %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %inc, 10
          br i1 %exitcond, label %for.end, label %for.body
```

When we first come across `%i.02`, the last label we passed was `entry`. Therefore, we are instructed to set `%i.02` to 0. Even though we have already passed the `for.body` label, the last predecessor block where a command was executed was in the `entry` block, making `entry` the last label. Next, we call our console print function. Then, we declare a variable `%inc` and set it to our 'i' variable + 1, and with this being the first increment, it would become 0. Lastly, we have a boolean comparison checking whether our 'i' value is less than 10, and in this case, it is, to which the `br` instruction sends us back to the top. Now is the tricky part: `phi` can tell that code was last executed in the `for.body` label. This means that we are still in the `for.body` predecessor block and `%inc` is still in our symbol table, which is why we can set `%i.02` to `%inc`. `%inc` will continue to be incremented until it is equal to 10, to which the `br` instruction will jump to the `%for.end` label, thereby exiting the loop.

For more information on all the instructions mentioned, visit the [LLVM Language Reference Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion of loops in LLVM IR, you have only labels and branches.

A loop that sum up number from 0 to 10 into variable `acc` can be written as three basic blocks:

```
%L0: ; loop init
  ; init i to 0 and acc to 0
  br label %L1
%L1: ; loop condition
  ; test if i <= 10, and store result in %cond
  br i1 %cond, label %L2, label %L3
%L2: ; loop body
  ; perform acc += i and i++
  br %L1
%L3: ; loop exit point
  ; the rest of the program
  ; ...
```

Note that the `br` instruction is used in two flavors, either it is a direct branch to a label or a conditional branch between two labels depending a boolean value (`i1` in LLVM parlance).

As a result, getting loop semantics back from IR requires analyses passes like `LoopInfo`.